# SSSD direct bind

Tags: linux, authentication, openldap, sssd

I use `openldap` with the following structure:

```
dc=example,dc=org
├── ou=groups
│   ├── cn=wheel
│   └── cn=adm
└── ou=users
    ├── uid=firstname.lastname
    └── uid=firstname.lastname
```

Every setup of SSSD I found use the setting `ldap_search_base`. But I have a simple structure and I would prefer to avoid to put an admin password in the config
file (or allow anonymous bind...).
Is there a setting similar to this:

```
ldap_direct_bind = "uid=%(user)s,ou=users,dc=example,dc=org"
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need (IMO you shouldn't have) an admin user to be provided as `ldap_default_bind`, all you need is an account which has read access to the necessary user attributes (defined in [RFC 2307](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2307.html)).

The problem with your approach is that user enumeration will probably not work, as the users are not guaranteed to have read access to the entire tree. This is a problem with ssh for example, as ssh checks the user's existence before attempting to authenticate.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I posted an issue on the project page: https://github.com/SSSD/sssd/issues/6376